# Color code tasks in calendar based on who it is assigned to

Tags: calendar, tasks

In Sharepoint tasks, in the calendar view, all the tasks are colored default blue. I'd like to be able to give different colors to it based on some criteria, preferably who the task is assigned to. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I to faced the same problem,then I used calendar overlay concept. For your scenario it is not good practice to create based on user(People Picker) i.e Assigned to for certain cases.

- Because we can't predict number of users,so we can't create view for all the users.

Better create view based on choice columns like Priority,
For your [reference](http://info.summit7systems.com/blog/color-code-calendar-events-in-sharepoint).

Thank you